# Liaison dans "et puis encore" en chantant

Tags: liaisons, paroles-de-chanson

Dans le texte de "Sur le pont d'Avignon" on trouve la phrase "et puis encore". J'ai ecouté des versions qui font la liaison entre "puis" et "encore" et des versions qui ne la font pas.

J'ai pense qu'en chantant on fait (presque) toutes les liaisons qui ne sont pas interdites.

Est-il bien le cas que cette liaison est facultative en chantant ou y a-t-il une version preferable dans ce cas ? Ou la raison pour les variations est-il le fait qu'on presente ce chanson aux enfants ?

Comment: J'aurais tendance à faire la liaison en poésie ou en chanson, sauf s'il y a une pause. Est-ce que les versions qui ne font pas la liaison ont une pause plus longue entre *puis* et *encore* que celles qui la font ?

Answer (score 2):

Le choix de faire la liaison dépend de l'interprète / locuteur et il n'y a à ma connaissance aucune obligation de faire les liaisons facultatives selon le type de texte. Pour la poésie et la chanson c'est avant tout une question de rythme et de nombre de syllabes qui détermine la diction.

Comment: En chanson effectivement le choix d'effectuer une liaison ou non est primordial afin de donner un style ou du rythme à sa chanson. Dans ce domaine particulier, quasiment tout est permis, et donc parfois (rarement) tu peux aussi trouver des liaisons interdites pour créer un effet de style. (criticable à mon goût, mais je ne suis que batteur :) )

Comment: J'ajouterais : le risque d'être incompris augmente lorsqu'on ne fait pas les liaisons. La rythmique de la chanson est imposée par la musique, il n'est pas toujours possible de bien marquer la séparation des mots. Sans liaison, on prononcent *épuiankor*. Il est parfois possible que ça prête à confusion, que l'oreille entende à peu près " Et puyant corps " et comprenne " Et pliant corps ", perturbant ainsi le sens de la phrase. En gros, on fait les liaisons parce qu'on a l'habitude de les faire et ainsi on s'assure que le langage utilisé est celui qui est codifié, identique pour tout le monde.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Les chansons ne respectent pas toujours la langue française ("Nous nous en allerons" - Renaud / Dès que le vent soufflera), souvent pour des effets de style.
Même si on n'en est pas à ces extrémités dans "Le pont d'Avignon", il faut aussi prendre note que cette chanson daterait de la fin du Moyen-Age, d'après Wikipédia... peut-être qu'à cette époque, on faisait moins les liaisons, et la chanson se serait transmise de bouche à oreille ainsi...
De manière générale dans les comptines pour enfants, il est fréquent d'avoir des paroles assez différentes d'une version à l'autre. Je présume qu'elles ont évolué au fil des âges...

Comment: Je trouve cette réponse trop éloignée de la question. Le cas de Renaud est une faute volontaire, alors que la *liaison facultative* est un cas général du français, de liaisons *conseillées mais pas obligatoires*, contrairement à d'autres qui sont interdites et d'autres qui sont obligatoires.

Comment: Bonjour,
L'exemple de Renaud est bien sûr _extrême_  (me relire), mais il illustre les libertés prises par les paroliers sur les règles du français, et ainsi toute la prudence requise lorsqu'on veut analyser un texte chanté en suivant les règles du français, pour les liaisons ou pour autre chose. Dans tous les cas, la liaison entre "puis" et "encore" est facultative, que ça soit _chanté_ (c'est la question initiale) ou pas. Elle se fait donc probablement à l'appréciation du chanteur, surtout qu'on ignore la volonté du parolier...